# Update to Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.4

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have VS 2017 v15.3.5.
According to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/10/10/visual-studio-2017-version-15-4-released/  v15.4 was released, but going to Extension and Updates, there's no update available

[image]

Comment: Up-voting to counter the needless down-vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft rolls out updates gradually (for multiple reasons, technical and non-technical), so you won't always be notified as the very first batch, even if they publishes the announcement.

If you do want to grab the latest bits, open the installer directly, and it should query the latest,

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installershell.exe`

Comment: Thanks. When I check manually by going to the Product Updates shouldn't it query the latest too? What's the difference to running that exe you mentioned? Also, is it safe to run that, are there any possible issues? What I mean, is, is that the latest stable I can get? Or I should better wait for official notification

Comment: @DonBox, if you are worried about stability issues, there is always a chance that these early releases can be a little bit problematic, that is why I am guessing that Microsoft does not releases them to VS straight away.

Comment: @KyloRen Yes, I am thinking the same. Thanks!

Comment: I have VS 15.3 offline installation, can I install that first and then upgrade to 15.4? Because download size is huge (20GB) and I want to save some money.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary you’d better open a new question as I don’t think there is a quick answer.